# Game Killer doesnt work in game c#

Tags: c#, process, kill

I'm trying to kill a game process by pressing F7. The app do work when the game is minimized and the form is on top. But when I'm playing the game (maximized) the app doesnt work. What can I do to solve this?

This is my code

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                 
    }   

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F7)
        {
          foreach (Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("processs"))
          {
              p.Kill();
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to hook into the windows keyboard events directly through p/invoke,. I'm not sure though how you say the code above is working, a form shouldn't be receiving key events in the constructor unless you possibly held the key down as you opened the form.

Answer (score 0):

When you press a key only the active window will get the message.  If this weren't true then every running program would have to actively ignore keystrokes.

If you want to be able to intercept keys even when not the active window then you need a global keyboard hook.  There are a few examples of this scattered around the web.  One that looks promising at first glance is [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C).

Comment: Except that [you cannot use managed code to create a global hook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318804)